# Visual Studio C# аналог #pragma mark из Xcode

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Есть подобный аналог [image: введите сюда описание изображения]в c#, а то падает читаемость кода при 999+ строк кода

Comment: Читать не пробовали [#pragma](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/preprocessor-pragma) и еще [#region](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2010/9a1ybwek(v=vs.100)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) - это все относится к [Preprocessor directives](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/preprocessor-directives/).

Comment: пробовал, не то. нужна нормальная навигация по файлу, как в Xcode

Comment: У меня нет XCode. Что значит "нормальная навигация по файлу"?

Comment: Если у вас плохая читаемость C# кода, то может стОит задуматься о хорошем оформлении и иерархии кода?

Comment: у вас на скрине нет ни pragma ни навигации. Что вам надо то? File Structure окно? (такое есть в решарпере)

Comment: @tym32167 В стандартном интерфейсе тоже есть структура файла. А если афтору нужно разделение на группы (`Multiplayer methods` `MultiplayerDelegate`) то лучше их вынести в отдельный файл чтобы 100500 методов не держать в одном файле.

Comment: картинка не моя, выложил для иллюстрации что нужно. У меня в файле около 12 методов, но есть очень длинные, что портит навигацию

Comment: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/viewing-the-structure-of-code?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Visual Studio Element Lsit]

Показывает все функции и переменные сегмента в котом находится курсор.

Раньше приходилось писать на ObjC, но этим выпадающим списком никогда не пользовался, хотя да, он чуть удобней чем в VS.

По мне, так для навигации `Code Folding` удобнее.

XCode: `Editor / Code Folding / Fold Methods & Funtions`

VS: `Правка / Структура / Свернуть/Рызвернуть Сегменты`